# Can't start SQL Server installation

Tags: windows-7, sql-server

I want to install SQL Server. I used the iso file `en_sql_server_2008_r2_standard_x86_x64_ia64_dvd_521546.iso`.

I extracted the files using 7zip and started `setup.exe` – a setup window opens for few a milliseconds and disappears.

I tried to start installation using Daemon Tools, the same problem occurred.

I have already one instance of SQL Server and want to install a second. My OS is Windows 7, 64-bit.

Comment: i hope this is due to some prerequisite files/software that support the installation is not in your PC.

Comment: Actually it is a little bit strange for me, because first instance of sql server I had installed using the same setup files

Comment: ys its strange and happened to me also. what i did is extracted exe and installed each software manually and then tried to install it normally.check this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2009/03/17/how-to-fix-your-sql-server-2008-setup-before-you-run-setup-part-ii.aspx) also

Comment: Where did you extract the files to? Can you try running setup.exe as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to compare the signature of the .iso file with the published hash to see if the file hasn't been corrupted during the network transfer.

The SHA1 hash of `en_sql_server_2008_r2_standard_x86_x64_ia64_dvd_521546.iso` should be: `09CF52A4209CA96FF480537BB86786F79AE0E8A3`

To calculate the hash: `sigcheck -h <file>`; [download Sysinternals Sigcheck](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441).

Comment: I see another [SHA1 hash of en_sql_server_2008_r2_standard_x86_x64_ia64_dvd_521546.iso](https://freetorrentz.net/74d9bc31a65a62d217c22fbb52370d5900c70dab]) to be `74D9BC31A65A62D217C22FBB52370D5900C70DAB`. Why should the hash be `09CF52A4209CA96FF480537BB86786F79AE0E8A3`?

Comment: My source is Microsoft itself: MSDN/Visual Studio ( https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=sql+server+2008+r2+standard - https://i.imgur.com/v1iE0Iw.jpg). Don't trust your source. If you want to develop an application and you need SQL Server you can download the developer edition for free: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Comment: I don't need a developer edition. My customer has lost their installation media. I want to have an installation DVD image, in case repairs are necessary in future.